# Unable to save and load Keras model

Tags: python, keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
...

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=number_training_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=number_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('last_try.h5')
```

I tried to save my model using `model.save('final_try.h5')`, as you can see above. But it doesn't seem to work. Then when I try to load a pre-existing first_try.h5, it doesn't work either
`from keras.models import load_model` `model = load_model('first_try.h5')`
This gives me the error `ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode.`

Comment: "But it doesn't seem to work." -- Why, in what way does it not work?

Comment: It does not save the file. No file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save and load keras model by 2 methods

1. you can save both weights and architecture in one .h5 file

   ```
   model.save('final_try.h5')
   ```

   and then easily load that

   ```
   model = load_model('first_try.h5')
   ```
2. you can save your weights in .h5 and your architecture in .json file seperately. so the error,

   ```
   ValueError: Cannot create group in read-only mode.
   ```

   means that you are trying to load just the weights of the model without its architecture. With this method you have to load the json architecture of the model or define it

   ```
   model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good explanation, although I found out the problem was that it was saving the model in the directory I was in, not in the same directory as my python file. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

save it like:

```
     model.save('model.h5')
     model_json = model.to_json()
     with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
         json_file.write(model_json)
```

Then for loading it into application efficiently, make it a global like following so that it doesn't load again and again:

```
    def load_model():

        global model

        json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
        model_json = json_file.read()
        model = model_from_json(model_json)
        model.load_weights("model.h5")
        model._make_predict_function()
```